# "ng g module" is generating some strange code inside module in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8

I am executing the command:

```
   ng g module componentes/top-bar --routing
```

I've looked inside top-bar.module.ts and there is this shit:

```
    {
  "_from": "@types/webpack-sources@^0.1.5",
  "_id": "@types/webpack-sources@0.1.5",
  "_inBundle": false,
  "_integrity": "sha512-zfvjpp7jiafSmrzJ2/i3LqOyTYTuJ7u1KOXlKgDlvsj9Rr0x7ZiYu5lZbXwobL7lmsRNtPXlBfmaUD8eU2Hu8w==",
  "_location": "/@types/webpack-sources",
  "_phantomChildren":
```

in the top-bar-routing.module.ts and there's some unwanted stuff.

This started happened all of a sudden. I've generated modules in the same application, I didn't change anything it was working before and worked fine.

Comment: Can you please provide us with more details? Does this happen with a new project? Have you ejected webpack for some reason? Have you tried to delete node_modules and do a `npm i`?

Comment: I can say this started to happen after I restarted my OS.

Comment: Try uninstalling Angular with `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` and do a fresh install. Also, try deleting node_modules and do a fresh `npm i`.

Comment: I've tried deleting the node_modules and reinstalled CLI but nothing. The problem seems to be related to the project itself. I created a new project and executed ng g module, now it didn't generate shit.

Answer (score 0):

I could search the web for a solution but I went the guaranteed way. I generated a new project, now I will pass all my code to the new project, fun stuff! Half a day lost. Yesterday I lost half a day with "ng new". The error wasn't less strange. It's going to be an "Angular week".